# How to stop httpd and mysqld from starting automatically when booting Fedora 27?

Tags: mysql, httpd, fedora, boot, rc.d

In the olden days, when I don't want mysqld and httpd to start by default when booting my Fedora Linux, I simply go to /etc/rc?.d (where ? is a number from 0 to 6, depending on the running level chosen) and then change the Kxxhttpd and Kyymysqld to Sxxhttpd and Syymysqld respectively (xx and yy are 2-digit numbers specifying the order of execution during OS startup).

But for newer versions of Fedora such as 27, does this mechanism change? I tried to do the same but the web server and the database daemons still start after reboot. What should I do to stop them from automatically running by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer Fedora versions (and many other distros, for that matter) use [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html) rather than the traditional sysvinit.

With systemd, services are [units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), which are managed through the [`systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) command. (The commands `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `enable`, `disable` come to mind in particular.)

[`systemctl disable <unit>`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#disable%20NAME%E2%80%A6) should do the trick for removing some unit from what should be automatically started/stopped.